# Adding Double field doesn't maintain precision in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.5

I have a shapefile that has an ID field(type=double, precision=15, scale=0). I am trying to add a new field(ID_2) that has the same field attributes as ID(Double,15,0). However, when I add the ID_2 field it seems like the new ID_2 field is being rounded to a precision=12.[image]

I've tried adding the new field both manually within ArcMap Desktop 10.5 and also using the Add Field tool in a Python script; both methods result in the ID_2 field being rounded and the last 3 digits replaced with zero's. I also imported the same streets shapefile into a file geodatabase, added the ID_2 field, and calculated from the ID field, and that worked exactly as I would expect.

Also strange is if I right-click on the new ID_2 field and go to Properties, it shows the Precision=0.[image]

Does anyone have any idea why my Double field isn't being added with a precision of 15, and is instead seemingly being rounded, chopping off the last 3 digits of the ID?

Comment: How did you calculate ID_2 to be the "same" as ID?

Comment: There's more than one numeric type in a dBase file.  ArcGIS only uses one of them for write, and I don't think that format supports a 15 width.  Floating-point values make unreliable identifiers for this reason.

Comment: With numbers that large I'd convert to text, for one of the reasons mentioned by @Vince above, create a text field for ID_2 and use field calculator to cast the numerals to string str([ !ID! ]) with Python. These are unique IDs that do not need to be numeric as the values will not be used in any analysis. Thay are simply an identifier.

Comment: @PolyGeo I right-clicked on the ID_2 field header and used Field Calculator (`ID_2 = !ID!`).

Comment: I am using TomTom shapefile street data which comes with the ID field as (Double, 15,0) which is displayed properly as shown in my screenshot above, so ArcMap can display a double field with 15 digits. I tried the exact same steps (adding ID_2 field and populating from ID) with the same data on a different computer running ArcMap 10.3 and ID_2 was calculated correctly with 15 digits. Either there is a bug in 10.5 or my ArcMap needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: The root cause seems to be when adding a new field, ArcMap doesn't honor what I enter for the Precision value. I just tried adding new Double type fields with Precision values of 12,10 and 2 and when I right-click on each of the three new fields and look at the properties, the Precision is set to 0.

Comment: This is a known ESRI bug. It existed in 10.4 and the previous case (BUG-000095512) was closed. It still exists in 10.5 and enough people have complained that ESRI has reopened the case under BUG-000099718. `BUG-000099718 : Numeric values stored in DOUBLE and FLOAT fields are corrupted in shapefiles created in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4 and 10.4.1. Shapefiles that are created at earlier versions perform correctly when opened in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.`

Comment: Please write your comments up as an answer.  It will be helpful if you can provide a link to that/those bug(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known ESRI bug, which has existed since 10.4. The original bug ([BUG-000095512](http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA5NTUxMg==/)) was determined to be "by design" and was closed. It still exists in 10.5 and enough people have complained that ESRI has reopened the case under [BUG-000099718](https://my.esri.com/#/support/bugs/BUG-000099718). The links may require you to have an ESRI account, so here is a screenshot of BUG-000099718. [image]